# Activity extending ActionBarActivity and YouTubeBaseActivity

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-youtube-api

In my application I need to `getSupportActionBar()` in order to change its title and enable home as back button. I also need to have a `YouTubePlayerView` to display a video. I cannot extend `ActionBarActivity` and `YouTubeBaseActivity` in the same time. What is the proper way to solve such problem?

Comment: you can use YouTubePlayerFragment

Comment: @brightstar ok, now in order to get to `getSupportFragmentManager()` which I need I have to extend `FragmentActivity' so I am back with the same problem

Comment: You can see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html, that ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity

Comment: @brightstar Yes, that solved all my problems. Thank you!

Comment: great, I added it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `YouTubePlayerFragment` instead of `YouTubeBaseActivity`. You will be able to extend your activity from `ActionBarActivity` which will allow to use both `getSupportActionBar()` and fragments.